# Trying to connect a Dlink DIR-615 router to a PPTP VPN from behind a Netgear WNDR3700

Tags: router, vpn, pptp

I have two routers: a Netgear WNDR3700 and a DLink DIR-615 (rev H2)

Both are using stock firmware.

The Netgear is my primary router (192.168.0.1/24). I'd like to set up the DLink (192.168.2.1/24) to connect to create a permanent connection to my VPN. The WAN port on the DLink is connected to one of the ethernet ports on the Netgear, and in the DLink admin interface I set the WAN connection type to "PPTP" and fill in the VPN details. When I click "save" the screen refreshes and "Cable Status" is "Connected", however "Network Status" remains "Disconnected" even if I click on the "Connect" button again.

I've tried putting the Dlink in the Netgear's DMZ to try and rule out any port forwarding kind of issue, but this didn't seem to make any difference. Am I forgetting some other configuration on either of the routers?